# Dictionary TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a simple program:

```
import pygame

textures = {"on_start.png":"(pygame image)","print.png":"(pygame image)"}

class block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,initx,inity,initp,initty,initte,initid):
        super().__init__()
        self.xpos = initx
        self.ypos = inity
        self.parent = initp
        self.blockType = initty
        self.texture = textures[initte]
        self.blockID = initid
        block_loop.add(self)

def load():
    global block_loop, block_store, blockNumber
    block_store = []
    block_loop = pygame.sprite.Group()
    pend1 = {"next":2,"0":{"type":"on_start","x":50,"y":50,"parent":-1},"1":{"type":"print","x":0,"y":0,"parent":0}}
    blockNumber = pend1["next"]
    del pend1["next"]
    for item in pend1:
        #print(pend1[item]["x"],pend1[item]["y"],pend1[item]["parent"],pend1[item]["type"],pend1[item]["type"] + ".png",item)
        block_store[item] = block(pend1[item]["x"],pend1[item]["y"],pend1[item]["parent"],pend1[item]["type"],pend1[item]["type"] + ".png",item)

load()
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.1)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*PATH*\program.py", line 27, in <module>
    load()
  File "C:\Users\*PATH*\program.py", line 25, in load
    block_store[item] = block(pend1[item]["x"],pend1[item]["y"],pend1[item]["parent"],pend1[item]["type"],pend1[item]["type"] + ".png",item)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I have print()ed the values (see the comment in line 24) and they were all printed correctly, so I do not know why I am getting this error. I have tried messing with the code for about an hour but keep getting this error, even though this is not a list but a dictionary and I could successfully accesses the values using the print() function via the same method used in defining the sprite. This is a very confusing problem and any help will be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I didn't include the pygame tag since I don't think it has anything to do with the problem.

QUESTION VERSION #2

Comment: Please, post [mre] that demonstrate your problem as well as full traceback you get

Comment: @buran         There, I tried to simplify it.

Comment: I think the error begins due to the fact that "block_store " is an empty list initially, and then you suddenly do block_store [item]= "something". Can you delete the "[item]" from the block_store [item] in the last line, and let us know the error shown after that?

Comment: @dimi_fn       Thanks for pointing that out to me, it should have been a dictionary, I didn't realize it was a list! Well, I changed it to `block_store = {}` The error makes sense now. I know it wasn't your comment's intention, but it answered my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over a dict, `pend1` you iterate over the keys. In your case, after deleting key `next`, `item` will take values `"0"`, `"1"`. These are `str` and as the error says, list indexes need to be integers. Even if these were `int` item assignment will not work, because the list starts empty. Because you want to use values, it is better to iterate over `pend1.items():`

```
for key, value in pend1.items():
    block_store.append(block(value["x"], value["y"], value["parent"], value["type"], f'{value["type"]}.png', key))
```

this will populate `block_store` with 2 elements of type block (by the way class names should be TitleCase, e.g. `Block`). Also order in which you iterate over dict items depends on python version. Before 3.7 dicts don't preserve order of insertion.

Comment: I use a dictionary since later entries will be deletable but all entries must retain their number, as well as this is saved as a json dictionary and when I used integers as dictionary names json raised an error. I have tried to write a script to convert the strings to integers using int() but it raised something about not converting strings to integers, and it is supposed to be a dictionary anyway. Thanks for trying to help, though. (See above comments)